# Expected Value of Event

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> A valuable treasure worth 100,000 is lost in a large swamp and it must be removed in one day. I can hire one or more helicopters. Helicopters cost 1000 per day and have a 90% chance of finding my treasure. How many helicopters should I hire?

Here's my solution.

Probability of not finding the treasure is 10%. If I hire $n$ helicopters, probability of not finding the treasure is

$$\frac{1}{10^n}$$

Probability of finding the treasure is

$$1-\frac{1}{10^n}$$

If I find the treasure, I gain 100,000 and lose $1000 \times n$ on helicopters. Net gain is $100,000 - 1000n$.

If I don't find the treasure, net gain is $-100,000-1000n$.

Using the expected probability's definition, expected value after hiring $n$ helicopters is

$$\left(100,000-1000n\right)\left(1-\frac{1}{10^n}\right) + \left(-100,000-1000n\right)\left(\frac{1}{10^n}\right)$$

Using this expression, [expected value for 2 helicopters](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(100000-1000*2)(1-1%2F10%5E2)%2B(-100,000-1000*2)%2F(10%5E2)) is 96000 and [expected value for 3 helicopters](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(100000-1000*3)(1-1%2F10%5E3)%2B(-100,000-1000*3)%2F(10%5E3)) is 96800. I also [graphed it](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zunyotwccl) and I found out that 3 helicopters has the highest expected value.

But my textbook says that the answer is 2. Please help me in finding my mistake.

Comment: If you do not find the treasure, you gain zero (not 100,000) and you lose 1000 times the number of helicopters.

Comment: And yes the answer is n=2, for an expected gain of 97,000.

Comment: And the expected gain for $n=3$ is $96,900$. The two expected values are very close. Maybe additional aspects should be taken into account.

Comment: @callculus: Why are extra considerations needed when a fewer number of helicopters is giving a higher expected value ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Something like uncertainty could be also taken into account. Why do you think the expected value is the only criteria for a decision of a human being ?

Comment: @callculus: Certainly, there are many criteria that can be adopted, and many considerations that might have to be taken into account in real life. I was only commenting w.r.t. an answer to a text book question on expected value.

Answer (score 2):

It is simpler to compute it as $(100,000)(1-\frac1{10^n}) - 1000n$,

since you have to shell out the money for the helicopters anyway.

For $n=2, E(X) = 97,000$

for $n = 3, E(X) = 96,900$

Answer (score 1):

Because it's an initial condition that the treasure is lost, for the purposes of this problem, finding the treasure will result in a gain of 100,000 minus expenses and not finding the treasure will result in a loss equal to your expenses (not 100,000 + expenses).

*Your initial state* is 100,000 lost, you have to minimize loss here.

If you hire n helicopters (assumed independent), probability of finding the the treasure is (1 - Probability no helicopter finds the treasure)

$ = (1 - \frac{1}{10^n}) $

So let's find our expected value:

$ E(\text{money gain}) = \text{Initial loss} + (100,000 - 1000n)*(1 - \frac{1}{10^n}) - (1000n * \frac{1}{10^n} )$

$= -100,000 + 10^5 - 10^{5-n} - n*10^3 + n*10^{3-n} - n*10^{3-n}  $

$=  - 10^{5-n} -n *10^3 $

If you take the global maximum of this, it's somewhere around 2.3

We can't send out 2.3 helicopters, so the answer has to be 2 or 3.

Value of expected gain at n = 2 is -1000 - 2000 = -$3000

At n = 3 it's - 100 - 3000 = -$3100

As a sanity check, n = 1 results in lower gain, and for anything higher than 3 the helicopters cost more than 3K so we can't beat -$3000.

Which is why **n = 2** is the answer.

Comment: Why add an answer repeating things that are already on the page?

Comment: I'm explaining why the 100,000 should not be counted as a potential loss AND potential gain for him. That was not on the page. I'm new here, if I'm misstepped in any way convention-wise let me know.